# WebService REST que reciba como parámetro un ArrayList<String> y también lo devuelva

Tags: java, json, rest, post

Tengo que hacer un web service REST que reciba como parámetro un `ArrayList<String>` y devuelva un `ArrayList<String>`.

Actualmente tengo un web service con GET que recibe un `String` y devuelve un `String` y funciona correctamente.

¿Se puede usar ArrayList como parámetro y retorno?, ¿debería ser POST?
¿Cómo se invocaría este servicio?

He leído que se podría utilizar el body y recibir un json, que también me serviría, pero no consigo entender cómo montarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Me tomo la libertad de suponer que estas haciendolo con un servidor de aplicaciones y alguna implementación de JAX-RS

```
package com.rest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("service")
public class Endpoint {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> example(List<String> list) {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Este ejemplo recibe una lista en forma de json, por ejemplo

```
["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

Y regresa una lista

```
["5", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

En mi caso estoy usando TomEE7, si nos indicas que servidor de aplicaciones y que implementación de JAX-RS usas sería más facil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

En webservices solo vas a poder enviar y recibir tipos string, es por esto que se suele usar **JSON**, para poder encapsular y dar formato a la información que enviamos o recibimos del webservice.

Te pongo un ejemplo de como hacer una llamada ajax con post, y recoger los datos del REST que devuelve un JSON.

```js
var restServer = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$.ajax(
  {
  url: restServer + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) 
    {
      var userid = data["userId"];
      var id = data["id"];
      var title = data["title"];
      var body = data["body"];
  
      $("textarea").html(JSON.stringify(data));
      $("#userid").html(userid);
      $("#id").html(id);
      $("#title").html(title);
      $("#body").html(body);
  
      
  
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="restData"></textarea>
<div id="userid"></div>
<div id="id"></div>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
```